# How to pass a string with # in url?

Tags: jquery, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user with name "k#arn". While passing that user through url it's taking only k.

```
"/users/auto_complete/?user_input=" + "k#arn"
```

above code is taking "k" as user name. Is there any way to escape # and pass the whole name ("k#arn") in the url?

Answer (score 3):

You should [`url_encode`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/ERB/Util/url_encode) that string:

```
require 'erb'

ERB::Util.url_encode('k#arn')
#=> "k%23arn"
```

It is not a good idea to build urls manually, whenever possible use Rails' named routes. In this example I would expect a route like `auto_complete_users_path(user_input: 'k#arn')`, but that depends on your use case and your routes file...